# Why do I get a "disabled" attribute on my anti-forgery token?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, csrf

I've a website in asp.net MVC 3, I just put some anti-forgery token, and I don't know why, in one of my forms(not others), I receive this exception:

```
A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.
```

It appears that in my html code, I've the following token:

```
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" 
type="hidden" value="0Ll0Io/fX0dR5HXCAroCKTKCBqNn2tmwgcqgYGjln8WVdWOPF2VQEen4wd2UKso1lpIstniXWjdgEE6m0ADgfRhIP25K12Y/ll+PFaYzoQgFAqSfL4XqNYKMrzvAKqmuqXnh3lwBFCYcDXKxRshKVefYelNfWgdFMtf8Ru/dT4qzWw9vU4KQS8eliglpzN9jXu5fekpBOsQGzOhoFHI3Ow==" 
disabled="disabled">
```

Why do I get this disabled attribute?

Here is some of my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("XXX", "YYY", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
...
}
```

and the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult XXX(SessionStore sessionStore, CurrentModel model)
```

I can't find anything on disabled on google :/(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code that generates the hidden field:

```
public HtmlString GetHtml(HttpContextBase httpContext, string salt, string domain, string path)
{
    string str = this.GetAntiForgeryTokenAndSetCookie(httpContext, salt, domain, path);
    string antiForgeryTokenName = AntiForgeryData.GetAntiForgeryTokenName(null);
    TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("input");
    builder.Attributes["type"] = "hidden";
    builder.Attributes["name"] = antiForgeryTokenName;
    builder.Attributes["value"] = str;
    return new HtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

As you can see there's no trace of any `disabled` attribute.

So the situation you are describing cannot happen unless:

1. You are using some custom built helper or custom built ASP.NET MVC
2. You have used javascript to add this attribute

Comment: You're right, in a jquery script I was disabling some input type, and it appears that this one was caught in the selector! Thank you